# Pyspark dataframe convert multiple columns to float

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert multiple columns of a dataframe from string to float like this

```
df_temp = sc.parallelize([("1", "2", "3.4555"), ("5.6", "6.7", "7.8")]).toDF(("x", "y", "z"))
df_temp.select(*(float(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df_temp.columns)).show()
```

but I am getting the error

```
select() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator
```

I cannot understand why this error is being thrown

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`float()` is not a Spark function, you need the function `cast()`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df_temp.select(*(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in df_temp.columns))
```

Comment: needs   pyspark.sql.functions import col

Comment: Where can I learn more about this syntax (col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in df_temp.columns) ? Here the"for" statement is coming after the action of casting.

Comment: is this supposed to be faster than nimerasam's answer? How can I apply this only to certain columns of the dataframe?

Comment: @hipoglucido instead of `df_temp.columns` you can provide a list of arbitrary columns

Comment: What is the * just after the select supposed to do here? Can someone please explain?

Comment: @ShreyMarwaha the star operator is a special operator in python that unpacks the contents of the tuple here, but it can be used on any iterable such as lists or sets as well.

Answer (score 38):

if you want to cast some columns without change the whole data frame, you can do that by **withColumn** function:

```
for col_name in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast('float'))
```

this will cast type of columns in cols list and keep another columns as is.
**Note**:
**withColumn** function used to replace or create new column based on name of column;
 if column name is exist it will be replaced, else it will be created

Answer (score 9):

If you want to cast multiple columns to float and keep other columns the same, you can use a single select statement.

```
columns_to_cast = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
df_temp = (
   df
   .select(
     *(c for c in df.columns if c not in columns_to_cast),
     *(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in columns_to_cast)
   )
)
```

I saw the withColumn answer which will work, but since spark dataframes are immutable, each withColumn call generates a completely new dataframe

Answer (score 1):

There is `withColumns` precisely for this. `df.select` subsets the dataframe to specified columns which may or may not be what you want.

Say there is an `exclude_list` - a list of all the columns you do not want to touch then

```
df_temp = df_temp.withColumns({i:F.col(i).cast(FloatType()) for i in df_temp.columns if i not in exclude_list})
```

should get your job done

Answer (score -3):

Here is another approach on how to do it :

```
cv = []   # list of columns you want to convert to Float
cf = []   # list of columns you don't want to change

l = ['float(x.'+c+')' for c in cv]
cst = '('+','.join(l)+')'

l2 = ['x.'+c for c in cf]
cst2 = '('+','.join(l2)+')'

df2rdd = df.map(lambda x : eval(cst2)+eval(cst))

df_output = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df2rdd,df.columns)
```

df_output is your required dataframe