# How to change all columns to double type in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to change all the columns of a spark dataframe to double type but i want to know if there is a better way of doing it than just looping over the columns and casting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark dataframe convert multiple columns to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478018/pyspark-dataframe-convert-multiple-columns-to-float)

Answer (score 5):

With this dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    (1,2),
    (2,3),
  ],
  ["foo","bar"]
)

df.show()
+---+---+
|foo|bar|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

the `for` loop is problably the easiest and more natural solution.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

for col in df.columns:
  df = df.withColumn(
    col,
    F.col(col).cast("double")
  )

df.show()
+---+---+
|foo|bar|
+---+---+
|1.0|2.0|
|2.0|3.0|
+---+---+
```

Of course, you can also use python comprehension:

```
df.select(
  *(
    F.col(col).cast("double").alias(col)
    for col
    in df.columns
  )
).show()

+---+---+
|foo|bar|
+---+---+
|1.0|2.0|
|2.0|3.0|
+---+---+
```

If you have a lot of columns, the second solution is a little bit better.

Answer (score -2):

First of all don't post a solution from PySpark on Spark questions. For beginners I find it really annoying. Not every implementation can be smoothly translated to Spark.

Suppose df if the DataFrame

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def func(column: Column) = column.cast(DoubleType)

val df2=df.select(df.columns.map(c=>func(col(c))): _*)
```