# PySpark how to iterate over Dataframe columns and change data type?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the best way to iterate over Spark Dataframe (using Pyspark) and once find data type of `Decimal(38,10)` -> change it to Bigint (and resave all to the same dataframe)?

I have a part for changing data types - e.g.:

```
df = df.withColumn("COLUMN_X", df["COLUMN_X"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

but trying to find and integrate with iteration..

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through `df.dtypes` and cast to `bigint` when type is equal to `decimal(38,10)` :

```
from pyspark.sql.funtions import col

select_expr = [
    col(c).cast("bigint") if t == "decimal(38,10)" else col(c) for c, t in df.dtypes
]

df = df.select(*select_expr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399474/11268096, where you can loop trough all columns and cast them to your desired data type.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

for col in df.columns:
  df = df.withColumn(
    col,
    F.col(col).cast("double")
  )
```