# How can I Cast Multiple columns in Pyspark using fold or Map Function?

Tags: pyspark

Currently I am using withColumn like below.

```
df_To_Cast.withColumn("ContractID", col("ContractID").cast('long')) \
        .withColumn("SNK_ContractNumber", col("SNK_ContractNumber").cast('string'))
```

Comment: You can use a for loop with `withColumn`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478018/pyspark-dataframe-convert-multiple-columns-to-float

Comment: Actually I don't want to use withColumn. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: No, you don't have any alternatives insted of using withColumn inside a for loop or other type of loop, or use an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use SQL:

```
df_To_Cast.createOrReplaceTempView("df_to_cast")

df_casted = spark.sql("""
                      SELECT 
                        CAST(ContractID AS LONG) AS ContractID, 
                        CAST(SNK_ContractNumber AS STRING) AS SNK_ContractNumber
                      FROM df_to_cast
                      """)
```

The query itself can be constructed within a for loop, of course.